# knotted 2-spheres in 4-space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

What would be example of "non-trivially" embedded sphere in 4-space and how to visualize?

We could have $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4 \subset S^4$ for topologists the 4-space can be "completed"  or "compactified"  to 4-sphere.  Can we get examples of non-trivially embedded 2-knots?

- $\pi_2(S^4 - S^2) = 0$
- $\pi_2(S^4 - S^2) \neq 0$

What do these "shapes" look like?  Have I written the invariants correctly? Any good strategies for visualizing such shapes?

---

Here is the discussion from Annals in Mathematics from 1959

- [Knotted 2-spheres in the 4-sphere](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970330) this is continuation of the result of Artin in 1930
- Zur Isotopie Zweidimensionaler  Flachen in $\mathbb{R}^4$
- [Singularities of 2-spheres in 4-space and cobordism of knots](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/osaka-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-2/Singularities-of-2-spheres-in-4-space-and-cobordism-of/ojm/1200691730.full)